# Saving performance by mapping over an array only once over twice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object

Can I save performance by mapping only once over an array instead of twice?
eg

```
const firstMapped = data.map(it=>...do stuff)
const secondMapped = data.map(it=>...do some other stuff)
```

Is it less expensive if I combine the 2 and return an array something like this

```
[
 {name:"firstMapped",data:{...},
 {name:"secondMapped",data:{...}}}
]
```

Option 1 is cleaner but I guess its more expensive, I can use just the variable names

Option 2 is possibly less expensive but I have to use is like

```
const firstMapped = mappedData[0]
const secondMapped = mappedData[1]
```

Comment: `data:{...}` What computation are you going to do here? is it a repeat of what you did in the first one, something like `data: data.map(it => ... do stuff)`?

Comment: "Can I save performance by mapping only once over an array instead of twice?" Of course, but then, is it worth? How big is the array? Did you benchmark how much runtime is spent in iterating over this array? Have the two iterations shared (expensive) logic? Basically, is this a Problem? Because it's not worth to write ugly unreadable/unmaintainable code if the savings are barely measurable.

Comment: There really should be no significant difference.  This is premature optimisation.  Use the cleaner code.   I suspect it's actually faster anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `reduce` to achieve the same result in a single pass. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
const { firstMapped, secondMapped } = data.reduce(
  (acc, item) => {
    // ...do stuff
    const firstMapped = ...;

    // ...do some other stuff
    const secondMapped = ...;

    // Accumulate the results
    acc.firstMapped.push(firstMapped);
    acc.secondMapped.push(secondMapped);

    return acc;
  },
  { firstMapped: [], secondMapped: [] }
);
```

The `reduce` function is used to iterate over the data array, computing both `firstMapped` and `secondMapped` for each item, and accumulating the results into two separate arrays within the accumulator object. The final result is an object containing two properties, `firstMapped` and `secondMapped`, which are arrays containing the results of the respective mapping operations.